# Lan connections Loadbalancer API Database

Tags: networking, network-security, loadbalancer

I'm Googling for several days and I can't find anything useful.

My question is how to wire up the complete backend servers.

So I have my router, loadbalancer from kemp, two hardware servers (one for the API backend, one for database).

The loadbalancer directs to different instances of the node js backend on server 1, server 1 should access server to the DataBase.

Whats better? Going from API to database over the switch or to hardwire the two servers directly?

And the important question is how to secure all that... DMZ, firewall, etc... I don't have any ideas and I only find how to set up loadbalancers with the routes etc but not how I should hookup the whole rack...

I'm thankful for every hint or solution!